# how to store datatable values in string variable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have stored table values in datatable i want to store each value in string  variable.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{      
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from tbl_invoice order by id desc", con))
    {
        if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        gvInvoice.DataSource = dt;
        gvInvoice.DataBind();
        gvInvoice.DataSource = dt;
        gvInvoice.DataBind();
        InvoiceNo = dt.TableName[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can Use Generics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
var myString = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

and if you dont want array then simply

```
string myString =dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

**EDIT:**

To extract by column name you can try like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{ 
    string mtstr1 = row["col1"].ToString();
    string mtstr2 = row["col2"].ToString();
    string mtstr3 = row["col3"].ToString();   
}
```

Comment: can we extract value by column name of table. because indexing is confusing . like dt.rows[0].["invoiceno"].tostring();

Comment: @krishnamohan:- Updated my answer!